# Mongo - possible in query to project subfield to top level?

Tags: mongodb

Document is e.g.

```
{ username : 'Fred', address : [ {country : 'USA'}, {country : 'Canada'}] }
{ username : 'James', address : [ {country : 'Canada'}, {country : 'Vietnam'}] }
{ username : 'Sally', address : [ {country : 'Vietnam'}] }
{ username : 'Alice', address : [ {country : 'USA'}] }
```

I want to query any records with an address in north America ie. Canada or USA, and return the location that matches as a top level element of the document.

The closest I have found to run the query is this, which returns the whole address document for the first record that matches:

```
coll.find(
{address: {$elemMatch : {country : {$in : ['USA', 'Canada']}}},
{'username': 1, 'address.$' :1 }
)
```

returns e.g.

```
{ username : 'Fred', address : [ {country : 'USA'} ] }
```

But is there a way to project the country directly into the document? ie.

```
{ username : 'Fred', address.country : 'USA' }
```

ideally something like `'address.$.country'` (but this doesn't seem to work). Neither does `'address.$.0.country'`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not do this using find because there is nothing like this in the projection [operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/). Why not to do this on application layer?

P.S. there might be a way to achieve this with aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

As Salvador Dali mentions, it is not possible to get it with projection operator. Following aggregation query might help you to get the result as you wish.

```
db.myObject.aggregate(
  {$unwind : "$address"},
  {$match : {"address.country" : {$in : ["USA", "Canada"]}}}
);
```

Result is returned as follows :

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5296faf86bdafa216cab1738"),
        "username" : "Fred",
        "address" : {
            "country" : "USA"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5296faf86bdafa216cab1738"),
        "username" : "Fred",
        "address" : {
            "country" : "Canada"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5296fb056bdafa216cab1739"),
        "username" : "James",
        "address" : {
            "country" : "Canada"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5296fb186bdafa216cab173b"),
        "username" : "Alice",
        "address" : {
            "country" : "USA"
        }
    }
]
```