# Rearrrange populated json result in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A simple json response for Post.find().populate("name") will return json result as follow. Note: The focus of the question is to rearrange the "name":"Alex" in json to the final structure as shown. Ignore the part that need hiding _id and __v. Thanks.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e6",
        "title": "Hello World",
        "postedBy": {
            "_id": "54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e4",
            "name": "Alex",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    ...
]
```

How could i rearrange and display the entire json as follow?

```
 [
        {
            "_id": "54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e6",
            "title": "Hello World",
            "name": "Alex"
        },
        ...
 ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo - possible in query to project subfield to top level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258679/mongo-possible-in-query-to-project-subfield-to-top-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** method to return a pure JSON object (not a mongoose document) that you can then manipulate using lodash helper methods such as **[`map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map)**, like in the following example:

```
Post.find()
    .populate("name")
    .lean().exec(function (err, result) {

        if(result){
            var posts = _.map(result, function(p) {
                p.name = p.postedBy.name;               
                p.postedBy = undefined;
                return p;
            });
            console.log(posts);
        }
    });
```

You can disable the `"__v"` attribute in your Schema definitions by setting the `versionKey` option to false. For example:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({ ... attributes ... }, { versionKey: false });
```

---

As follow-up to your question on rearranging the order of the properties in the JSON, JS does not define the order of the properties of an object. However, you 
can use both the **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** and **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** methods to change the order, for example

```
var json = {    
    "name": "Alex",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "_id": "54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e6"
};
console.log(json);

//change order to _id, title, name
var changed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json, ["_id","title","name"] , 4));
console.log(k);
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var json = {    
    "name": "Alex",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "_id": "54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e6"
};


//change order to _id, title, name
var changed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json, ["_id","title","name"] , 4));

pre.innerHTML = "original: " + JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + "</br>Ordered: " + JSON.stringify(changed, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: hi, how do i rearrange the json property in specific order

Comment: @stackdisplay JS does not define the order of the properties of an object but you can construct a workaround, check my updated answer.